# Dynamically create an object in C(using radiohead library)

Tags: c, arduino

I am trying to implement dynamic address assignment on my arduino using an NRF24l01+, but I can't get a RHReliableDatagram initialized globally after my unit receives it's assigned address

This is what I have(which for some reason doesnt work:

```
manager = new RHReliableDatagram(driver, ID);
```

Error:

```
sketch_oct02b.ino: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_oct02b:47: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'manager = (((RHReliableDatagram*)operator new(267u)), (<anonymous>->RHReliableDatagram::RHReliableDatagram(((RHGenericDriver&)(& driver.RH_NRF24::<anonymous>.RHNRFSPIDriver::<anonymous>)), ((uint8_t)ID)), <anonymous>))'
C:\Users\****\Documents\HAS\HAS-mc\libraries\RadioHead/RHReliableDatagram.h:66: note: candidates are: RHReliableDatagram& RHReliableDatagram::operator=(const RHReliableDatagram&)
```

This is code that works, but I cant change the address during runtime.

```
RHReliableDatagram manager(driver, DHT1_ADDRESS);
```

A minimal reproduction of my problem here:

```
#include <RHReliableDatagram.h>
#include <RH_NRF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <DHT.h>

RH_NRF24 driver(8,10);

int ID = 255; //init ID, will be reassigned by server
RHReliableDatagram manager(driver,ID);//255 is the ID before init


void setup() 
{
  ID = 15;
  manager = new RHReliableDatagram(driver, ID);//NOTE added this
  //spi.setPins(13, 4, 3); //miso mosi sck
  if (!manager.init()){
    Serial.println("NRF failed to initialise");
    digitalWrite(PIN_NRF_ERROR,HIGH);
  } else {
    Serial.println("NRF succesfully initialized");
  }
}

void loop()
{

}
```

The documentation for the radio head library is here:
http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRHReliableDatagram.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the dynamic allocated object to the pointer of that object type, such as

```
type *p_var = new type(initializer)
```

In your code it should be remove

```
RHReliableDatagram manager(driver,ID);//255 is the ID before init
```

and change

```
manager = new RHReliableDatagram(driver, ID);//NOTE added this
```

to

```
RHReliableDatagram *manager = new RHReliableDatagram(driver, ID);//NOTE added this
```

Also you need to remember to use `delete()` to free the memory that the manager when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am late but - there is a function to do that.

Use:

```
manager.setThisAddress(ID);

void RHDatagram::setThisAddress(uint8_t thisAddress)
{
    _driver.setThisAddress(thisAddress);
    // Use this address in the transmitted FROM header
    setHeaderFrom(thisAddress);
    _thisAddress = thisAddress;
}
```